# Connection authorization failure using Maven SQL plugin

Tags: maven, db2, continuous-integration, maven-plugin

I am using Maven SQL plugin to execute script on DB2 database, here is the configuration.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <configuration>

          <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:db2://SERVER:50000/TEST</url>
          <username>DB2ADMIN</username>
          <password>iJur$$99X</password>

        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>drop-table</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <autocommit>true</autocommit>
              <sqlCommand>DROP TABLE person</sqlCommand>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>create-table</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <autocommit>true</autocommit>
              <srcFiles>
                <srcFile>src/main/sql/schema.sql</srcFile>
              </srcFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Content of `src/main/sql/schema.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255));
```

Executing the build using this command:

```
>mvn test -e
```

Got below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (drop-table) on project I3LOC: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.3.111] 
Connection authorization failure occurred.  
Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (drop-table) on project I3LOC: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.3.111] 
Connection authorization failure occurred.  
Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQL STATE=28000
```

Installed `db2jcc.jar` to local Maven repository using this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\vinu\workspace\Maven\BatchFramework\lib\db2jcc4.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4 -DartifactId=com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**Note: the credential specified (DB2ADMIN, iJur$$99X) is correct, Using this credential I am able to connect to TEST database**

Comment: Don't know if it is related to your problem, but `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` is invalid syntax in DB2 SQL.

Comment: @mustaccio: Corrected and tested with same error!!! I was testing the same plugin with mysql, The above plugin works fine with MYSQL, however for DB2 it does not work

Comment: Are you sure Maven is not interpreting "$$" in some funny way? Try changing your password to something without special characters.

Comment: @mustaccio: You may be right, I need to check by changing the password by taking help from DBA

Answer (score 0):

1. The above maven configuration works fine with plain password, As pointed out by mustaccio the issue is due to special ($$) char in password.
2. I will raise a defect with sql plugin team to fix the issue.